# How to get Bitmap from NetworkImageView

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

I want Bitmap from networkimageview. here is my code and

```
    String url="https://graph.facebook.com/"+u_id+"/picture";
    mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);
    mImageLoader = MySingletonClass.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
    mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(url, mImageLoader);
```

After this I want bitmap from networkimageview. how to get it?

Answer (score 6):

```
        mImageLoader.get(url, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {

        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
           // image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_error); // set an error image if the download fails
        }

        public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
            if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                mNetworkImageView.setImageBitmap(CircleImage.getRoundedRectBitmap(response.getBitmap(), 100));
            } //else
               // image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_loading); // set the loading image while the download is in progress
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have the same problem, I want to get the bitmap from the NetworkImageView, and I used volley as well..

could you please explain your answer more in detail please?

Comment: Any ideas why your solution would display an empty image?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mNetworkImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

**EDIT:**

I check the `Volley` code and found that they are using a tag to store info about the image, so, try this:

```
ImageContainer container = (ImageContainer) mNetworkImageView.getTag();
final Bitmap bitmap = container.getBitmap();
if (bitmap != null) {
    //other code to processing bitmap
}
```

Comment: I already tried that. its giving me NullPointerException. I think because we are not attaching image to neworkimageview,everytime activity loads it fetches from fb or cache.

Comment: No its givingme NullPointerException at final Bitmap bitmap = container.getBitmap();

Comment: I think you are trying to get the bitmap too early, so the bitmap has not been loading at that time.

Comment: I got solution, we have to use ImageListener. I am writing code in answer